# Why my PayPal button doesn't show item's name

Tags: java, paypal

In my app, when I am building the encrypted PayPal button as following:

```
buffer.append("business="      + Constants.SYSTEM_PAYPAL_BUSINESS_EMAIL + "\n");
buffer.append("cert_id="       + Constants.SYSTEM_PAYPAL_CERTIFICATE_ID + "\n");
buffer.append("charset=UTF-8\n");
buffer.append("currency_code=SGD" + "\n");
buffer.append("return="        + Constants.SYSTEM_STUDENT_HOMEPAGE + "\n");
buffer.append("cancel_return=" + Constants.SYSTEM_STUDENT_PATH + "RegisterPlacementTest.xhtml" + "\n");
buffer.append("notify_url="    + Constants.SYSTEM_STAFF_PATH + "ConfirmPlacementTest.xhtml" + "\n");
buffer.append("item_name="     + reservedPackage.getName() + "\n");
buffer.append("item_number="   + reservedPackage.getId() + "\n");
buffer.append("amount="        + (reservedPackage.getPrice() - reservedPackage.getDiscount()) + "\n");
buffer.append("custom="        + reservationID);
```

I expected to see my Package's name to appear on PayPal checkout page. However, I saw, instead, an input text field to enter the item description. I checked with `System.out.println` and can confirm that `reservedPackage.getName()` is not empty or null.

I'd be very grateful if you could show me what I have done wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I had to move these 3 lines:

```
buffer.append("item_name="     + reservedPackage.getName() + "\n");
buffer.append("item_number="   + reservedPackage.getId() + "\n");
buffer.append("amount="        + (reservedPackage.getPrice() - reservedPackage.getDiscount()) + "\n");
```

up to place it before the `currency_code` line as following:

```
...
buffer.append("charset=UTF-8\n");
buffer.append("item_name="     + reservedPackage.getName() + "\n");
buffer.append("item_number="   + reservedPackage.getId() + "\n");
buffer.append("amount="        + (reservedPackage.getPrice() - reservedPackage.getDiscount()) + "\n");
buffer.append("currency_code=SGD" + "\n");
...
```

and it worked perfectly. I have no idea why the problem occurred in the 1st place but this is the solution :P.